# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 restart/shut-down halts due to a not responding program. How to stop it?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, restart, ubuntu-mate

On my Ubuntu MATE 16.04, whenever I press shutdown, restart button, I get a message that `at-spi-registryd.desktop` program is not responding and I either need to wait for the program to finish or I could reboot/shutdown anyway (warns me that I may lose work). Why does this happen? How can I make the shutdown/restart process smoother ie. not see that message and restart/shutdown the normal way?

[image: This is a screen shot of that message.]

Comment: Check this: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/issue-shutting-down-16-04-at-spi-registryd-desktop/5435

Comment: Thanks your link helped. I just disabled the executable `/usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd` using `sudo-caja` and everything is working properly. I wanted to know if there is any downside of not making the aforementioned file executable.

Comment: No, the only downside is that some "Assistive technology" apps (such as screen reader or on-screen keyboard) may not work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a regression of this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/729827

So, the workaround (provided you dont need assistive technologies) would be:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd.old
```

This renames the file for `at-spi2-registry` so that the system won't run it, but maybe you also want to reopen it on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to "maybe have" fixed this problem was to use Caja as root to rename /user/lib/
and renamed the "at-spi-core  directory (folder)" to ORGat-spi-core. 
That seemed to solve the problem so far. It may not been the proper way but it has worked so far.